# Thinkster.io MEAN stack issue setting up Authentication Routes

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

Thinkster link: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/node-json-api/setting-up-users-and-authentication

I'm unable to start my application running npm start having followed along with this course. I've followed it closely and when I go to run npm start, it comes up with up ERR! code ELIFECYCLE.

It's also mentioning the line of code for the username as a point of error.

username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"], match: [/^[a-zA-zO-9]+$/, 'is invalid'], index: true},

Unfortunately, being very new to this, I can't work out what's going on!

Comment: Hi huttiepant, welcome to SO. Could you please provide the code you are using? The link you provided could not be available. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @axl-code, good to be here - hopefully this isn't too stupid a question! I don't exactly know how to share my code with you though, can you let me know how to do that?

Comment: Just add all the code you think is related with your question, after that the community will give you feedback if they need more information ;)